# Variable in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in which I will have a variable, so I want to declare the variable in the beginning. My variable type is a date.

I want to have something like this:

```
Declare @RepportDate

Select t.ID,
       t.FullName,
       t.amount
From myTable as t
WHERE t.OperationDate=@RepportDate
```

Then I can use this variable more than one time after.

Comment: The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has a pretty in-depth section on declaring and using variables in T-SQL

Comment: What is your question here; you seem to have forgotten to ask one. Also, your `DECLARE` statement is missing the datatype for your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the datatype when declaring the variable.

```
Declare @RepportDate Date

Select t.ID,
       t.FullName,
       t.amount
From myTable as t
WHERE t.OperationDate=@RepportDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @RepportDate Date
Set @RepportDate = '2019-01-01'
Print @RepportDate
```

or

```
Declare @RepportDate DATE = '2019-01-01'
Print @RepportDate
```

You may want to set it to a value straight away if it will be static.